# Conditionally hide console in C

Tags: windows, console

Currently I use `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` when compiling my application for windows so that it runs without a console window, however now I want to support a conditional console mode (e.g. as a command line or config parameter) so I need a way to only sometimes hide the console window. Is there a way to achieve this for windows?

Comment: Have you checked [the Windows console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for something suitable?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've never used windows-only APIs, but `AllocConsole` seems to do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: You might also need to create stdin and stdout; I am not sure. That probably only applies to GUI programs and if yours is a console window with no console initially then it probably has stdin and stdout already.